# Why don't touch events stop when a dialog shows?

Tags: android

I have a ListView whose child views have long-click listeners set.  When a child view is long-clicked, a dialog shows.

The problem is that if the user keeps their finger pressed after the dialog shows then they can still scroll the ListView, even though the ListView is now behind the dialog.  Through debugging, I've found that all touch events (e.g., `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP`) are still being received in the original window, until the user finally lifts their finger.

Here's a short reproducible example:

```
package foo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView = new ListView(this);
        listView.setAdapter(new FooAdapter());
        setContentView(listView);
    }
}

class FooAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final Context context = parent.getContext();

        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setText("Text");
        textView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setMessage("Hi")
                    .show();
                return true;
            }
        });

        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

On Android 6.0, 7.0, and 7.1, the ListView continues to be scrollable even after the dialog takes focus if the user never lets go of the child view.  This seems to happen only the first time the dialog shows (until the activity is created again).

I have two questions:

1. Is this an Android bug?  What's happening is that the touch gesture is running to completion (from `ACTION_DOWN` to `ACTION_UP`) even though the window loses focus before `ACTION_UP`.  I can't imagine this ever being desirable behaviour.
2. What's the best solution here?  The following solution (ignoring all touch events after the window loses focus) works, but I wonder whether there's something better:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       ...

       @Override
       public void dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
           if (hasWindowFocus()) {
               return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
           } else {
               return true; // suppress
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note that I can't use `AbsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener`, which solves this problem by ignoring all touch events after a long-click has been detected, because it's too inflexible.

Comment: Try calling `setCancelable(false)` on the `AlertDialog.Builder` instance.

Comment: @Emmanuel Same problem when using `setCancelable(false)`.

Comment: Did you managed to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure the way events work on Android. 
In my mind, when you click on screen, base on your coordinates, android will specify the view process this event. Because user still not release scroll view event, so this view still is understood that is processing this event.

Just work around listView.setEnable(true) before you show dialog.

Best practice, create custom dialog or util to create dialog with listeners:

before show -> disable listView
before dismiss -> enable listView